# laravel installation error php version: This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: php, laravel-5

my php version is 7:

```
C:\xampp\php>php -v
```

> PHP 7.2.0 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2017 00:17:00) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x86 ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

but when I create new project I get this errors:

> C:\xampp\htdocs>laravel new site
>
> Crafting application...
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 2
>
> - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0].
> - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 3
>
> - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.5.32 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.32].
> - laravel/framework v5.5.32 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 4
>
> - Installation request for swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.0.2 -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.0.2].
> - swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.0.2 requires php >=7.0.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 5
>
> - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[4.2.0].
> - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 6
>
> - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 5.3.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[5.3.0].
> - phpunit/php-code-coverage 5.3.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 7
>
> - Installation request for phpunit/php-token-stream 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-token-stream[2.0.2].
> - phpunit/php-token-stream 2.0.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 8
>
> - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.5.5].
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 9
>
> - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 5.0.6 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[5.0.6].
> - phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 5.0.6 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 10
>
> - Installation request for sebastian/comparator 2.1.2 -> satisfiable by sebastian/comparator[2.1.2].
> - sebastian/comparator 2.1.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 11
>
> - Installation request for sebastian/diff 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[2.0.1].
> - sebastian/diff 2.0.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 12
>
> - Installation request for sebastian/environment 3.1.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/environment[3.1.0].
> - sebastian/environment 3.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 13
>
> - Installation request for sebastian/exporter 3.1.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/exporter[3.1.0].
> - sebastian/exporter 3.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 14
>
> - Installation request for sebastian/global-state 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/global-state[2.0.0].
> - sebastian/global-state 2.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 15
>
> - Installation request for sebastian/object-enumerator 3.0.3 -> satisfiable by sebastian/object-enumerator[3.0.3].
> - sebastian/object-enumerator 3.0.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 16
>
> - Installation request for sebastian/object-reflector 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/object-reflector[1.1.1].
> - sebastian/object-reflector 1.1.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 17
>
> - Installation request for sebastian/recursion-context 3.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/recursion-context[3.0.0].
> - sebastian/recursion-context 3.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 18
>
> - Installation request for theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by theseer/tokenizer[1.1.0].
> - theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 19
>
> - laravel/framework v5.5.32 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - laravel/tinker v1.0.3 requires illuminate/console ~5.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.32].
> - Installation request for laravel/tinker v1.0.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v1.0.3].

Application ready! Build something amazing.

Comment: clear your composer cache, also try to remove your composer.lock [don't forget to backup it]

Comment: Can you run `php -v` again from xampp/htdocs, instead of xampp/php? Just in case a different binary is used from the PATH